# How to setup staging and production app for Facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, android-productflavors

I am adding Facebook auth to app for sign up (with Firebase auth).

Issue is I have different flavor for dev and prod apps, so bundle ID for iOS and app ID for Android is different: `dev (com.example.dev)`and`prod (com.example)`.

Facebook require:

*Android:*

**5. Associate Your Package Name and Default Class with Your App**

**6. Provide the Development and Release Key Hashes for Your App**

*iOS:*

**3a. Add your Bundle Identifier**

Is solution to set up test Facebook app for development app, and normal Facebook app for production app?

Comment: create a child app in the app settings

Comment: @luschn Thanks for reply! You mean Test app for dev mobile app?

Comment: yes, you can easily set it up in the app settings

Comment: @luschn Thanks! Can I give same `Development and Release Key Hashes` for prod and dev app?

Answer (score 3):

You can create Test Versions for an App directly in the App settings: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/

They are like child Apps, with different App ID and different settings. For example, you can set a different Key Hash for the Android platform.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am just use flavor for different app ID so I am use same key hash. Is Facebook allow use same key hash?

Comment: i just opened a test app and it seems that you can set the same, yes. app id and app secret have to be different though.